# Vertical menu with menu button pressed

Tags: android, menu, contextmenu, menuitem, submenu

I would like to create a vertical menu to appear in the middle of the screen when the Menu button is pressed.I've implemented it and it appears in the bottom of the page but not the one i would like... Hereunder my code and my goal picture to achieve

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >


 <item
    android:id="@+id/expandall"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Expand All"/>


<item
    android:id="@+id/collapseall"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="withText"

    android:title="Collapse All"/>


<item
    android:id="@+id/myprofile"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="withText"
    android:title="My Profile"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/signout"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Sign Out"/>
```

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.collapseall:
        // Single menu item is selected do something

        collapseAll();

        return true;

    case R.id.expandall:

        expandAll();

        return true;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Seems its not easy..huh

Comment: Please help me folks...